# JavaScript: Is there any "python's Generator" equivalent in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, iteration

*Is there any "python's Generator" equivalent in JavaScript?*

*PS:*
Python's Generator is very memory efficient when we need to do **one time** iterate through a **big** array, hash... 
*"Generators are iterables, but you **can only read them once**. It's because they do not store all the values in memory, **they generate the values on the fly**"*

(Python's Generator explained in this thread: [What does the "yield" keyword do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in a standard way. Some browsers [already implement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) python-style generators, but they require extensions that need to be explicitly activated.
There are proposals to [add generators](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=proposals%3aiterators_and_generators) to a next version of the ECMAScript spec, but I wouldn't see that being useable very soon.

So far, the best you can do is to use the old school [external iterator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator) pattern. It is just as powerful, although it is a pain to write in more complicated cases.

Comment: Thanks Missingno! The external iterator pattern is nice and new to me.. I'm trying to learn more about that..

Comment: Yield is comming!  Now already in FireFox - soon to be in Chrome.
http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:generators
http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2355

Answer (score 2):

It's not super practical, but you can achieve the same basic effect like this:

```
function make_generator(start, end) {
  var i=start;
  return function() {
    if (i<end) {
      output = i;
      i += 1;
      return output;
    }
    else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
var out = document.getElementById('out');
var generator = make_generator(1,10);
var g = generator();
while (g) {
  if (out.innerHTML)
    out.innerHTML = out.innerHTML + '<br>' + g;
  else
    out.innerHTML = g;
  g = generator();
}
```

Comment: I prefer the approaches of returning a custom object or throwing an exception to signal the end of iterations. Those allow you to iterate over things that contain null or undefined members as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `yield` keyword. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) (MDN).

> The yield keyword is used to pause and resume a generator function

```js
function* range(n) {
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        yield i;
    }
}

const generator = range(10);

console.log(generator.next());  // { value: 0, done: false }
console.log(generator.next());  // { value: 1, done: false }
...
console.log(generator.next());  // { value: 9, done: false }
console.log(generator.next());  // { value: undefined, done: true }
```

Notice the `*` after the `function` keyword.

It's widely supported now: [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/es6-generators), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield#browser_compatibility)

---

TypeScript notation:

```
function* range(n: number): IterableIterator<number> {
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        yield i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript 1.7:

```
function rangeGen(n) {
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++)
        yield i;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, but Yield only supported in Firefox with a tag <script type="application/javascript;version=1.7">.. maybe we should wait until yield comes to mainstream with more browser to get that support..

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield Shows `yield` is widely supported now. But not by IE.